# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas on TEST RPC

Tags: testrpc

```
   function allowServiceProvider(bytes32 _name,uint _votes) ifDivOptExecuted {
    // CSD can allow a service provider to submit its customers votes
    if(_votes > divOpt.votingRightsMax - divOpt.votingRightsUsed){
      // throw in case you give more votes to the service provider than allowed
      throw;
    }
    // used to dynamically map index to structure in array of structs
    // to be refactored..
    address _sp =msg.sender;
    providerOf[_sp].name = _name;
    providerOf[_sp].votingRightsMax =_votes;
    providerOf[_sp].votingRightsUsed = 0;
    providerOf[_sp].active = true;
    SpStatus('Service Provider allowed by CSD (name,votes)',_name,_votes);
  }
```

THE TRANSACTION IS CALLED LIKE THIS:

```
DividendOptionContract.deployed().then(function(instance)
  {
    return instance.allowServiceProvider(name,votes,{from:web3.eth.accounts[5]
});
  }).then(function(result)
         {
            save_th(result.tx,type)
            console.log("done");

         }).catch(function(e){
           console.log(e);

         });
```

Comment: What are divopt and ifDivOptExecuted? It's very likely this is throwing by design.

Comment: IfdivOptexecuted is a modifier which checks if a value is true (which i have set to true)  and the if condition will evaluate to false i am sure of that !

Comment: I debugged the error. Too much gas was being used because of the number of assignments and operations. when i commented out the event catcher the code worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the error. Too much gas was being used because of the number of assignments and operations. when i commented out the event catcher the code worked perfectly !